# Copy a range of cells with certain criteria. Paste correct criteria as transpose

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, transpose

I am working on a project where column G has an If Statement:

```
=IF(AND(E2>0,E2<6),COUNTIF($E$2:$E$58,E2),"")
```

I want to be able to use a macro that will loop through the range and copy all values with a count in them. However, I do not want to copy column E, I need the information from column A that corresponds with column E's count. Column A is the Bin Location. After that I would like to be able to transpose those values into B72.

Here is what I am thinking logically, but I am not too strong in VBA and need some help.

```
If range.cell(Column E) <> " " then

'grab that cell and go over to column A value and copy. Next cell

'Store all the values(Column A) and transpose starting at B72
```

Comment: You are going to be better off dumping your loop results to a new sheet for easy use.  Or you could do a filter perhaps.

Comment: Quick note - I know you're only starting with it as an example, but that IF loop will always run - you are looking for NO space - but your formula will return an empty cell. It's `" "`  or `""`.  It looks like you might instead be able to use Index/Match to return those values that have a count.  Can you post some sample data and a sample "finished" table?

Comment: I understand that it has to be ended, that is not my problem. I will post something momentarily.

Comment: Apparently I cannot post anything because I do not have a 10 reputation. Just got the account today.

Comment: You can host off-site on imgur or something and add the links.  A mod or 2000 rep user can edit the pictures in for you.

Comment: Check @brad mahan's post.

Comment: So basically, in G, if there is a value, copy the corresponding Section (Column A) and transpose paste so that I can go on to use a VLOOKUP for the rest of the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify before I go any further in my answer, are you basically trying to copy and transpose (paste values) to a different location within a Macro?  If so what is the qualifier from Column E that signifies that you should look up column A?

I am also working with Dinjo on this project. Here is his examples.

[image: Data]

[image: Result]